# Having Trouble with Correct output from If statement

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

I could use some help with an assignment. The user has to enter the number of students and then enter scores and I have to find the best score and assign a grade accordingly.

Grade is A if score is >= best-10

Grade is B if score is >= best-20

Grade is C if score is >= best-30

Grade is D if score is >= best-40

Grade is F otherwise

My program is not producing the correct grades at the moment and I tried putting another for loop right before my if but nothing changed and then I tried using another variable (j instead of i) but I'm sort of stuck. I'm new to java so any help would be appreciated, and thank you in advance :)

Here is an example of the input and output:

Enter the number of students: 4

Enter 4 scores: 45 90 78 23

Student 0 grade is: A

Student 1 grade is: A

Student 2 grade is: A

Student 3 grade is: C

It's hard to tell if the best score is being determined because it gives the same score to other numbers, this happens with many other numbers as input.

```````````````````````````````````````````````
       ``````````````````````````````````````````````
          import java.util.Scanner;
          public class Main
            {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
           int students = input.nextInt();

            int[] grades = new int [students];


            System.out.print("Enter " + students + " scores: ");
            for(int i=0; i<students; i++){
              grades[i] = input.nextInt();
          }

           int max = grades[0];
           for(int i = 0; i<grades.length; i++){

            if(grades[i] > max){
                max = grades[i];
            }

           for(i = 0; i<grades.length; i++){
             if (grades [i] >= max-10){
                 System.out.println("Student " + i + " score is: A");
              }else if (grades[i] >= max-20){
                 System.out.println("Student " + i + " grade is: B");
              }else if (grades [i] >= max-30){
                 System.out.println("Student " + i + " grade is: C");
              }else if (grades[i] >= max-40){
                 System.out.println("Student " + i + " grade is: D");
              }else{
                 System.out.println("Student " + i + " grade is: F");
              }
             }
            }
            }
           }
        `````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: "My program is not producing the correct grades" how exactly? What input did you use? What output did you get? What output did you expect?

Comment: Is at least the max correctly determined?

Comment: Are at least the right number of inputs taken? Correctly stored? Possible to be listed back to the output?

Comment: All of that is considered basic debugging? What else did your try to find the problem?

Comment: @Yunnosch  I've inputted many scores and none of them have been correct.

Comment: That somehow seems to not answer any of my questions. Try with fewer scores and make an explicit example of it. Show it here by [edit]ing your question. Explain what you perceive as "wrong" about the shown grades, e.g. by stating those you expected.

Comment: Yes, the correct number of inputs are taken. If you see anything wrong with my code, please let me know

Comment: @Yunnosch Should I display the input and output as an image of the program running?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your code just like that. That is why I ask you to provide more information and to do some basic debugging. Please do not answer my questions with "Yes/No." Prove it by showing results and details.

Comment: No. Please show your results as text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: @Yunnosch okay I showed my results

Comment: @Yunnosch You also asked a yes or no question so I answered yes or no, I don't see the problem with that. Also, I said the outputs are wrong and the 'expected" results should be what I have in my If statements, regardless of what numbers I input.

Comment: I think it was Churchill who once famously got through a whole interview (done by a very inexperienced reporter who had somehow annoyed him) by saying nothing but "Yes" or "No" in answer to many questions. I admire your willingness to live up to a dervedly famous historlcal idol. I recommend however that for getting an answer to you coming questions on StackOverflow you provide more detailed debugging information without being prompted one by one. Making a good [mre], including input, output and expected output is an important part of that. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: I have to apologise by the way. I actually **did** see somethign wrong with your code, which was the lack of consistent indentationand correct markdown. If I had mentioned that and made you fix it, the problem (as nicely shown by the answer) would have become obvious immediatly. I unwisely decided to first get you provide more details. Sorry.

Comment: I said in my question that the grade outputs were not accurate and if you look at the if statements then its clear to see what the output should be regardless of the numbers I chose to put. Again, you asked if the correct number of inputs are taken, which is a yes or no question so I answered 'yes' and said if you saw anything wrong with my code then to please let me know, which you also didn't do. Which is the whole point of being on this site if your intention is to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally your code is fine, there was an issue with calculating `max` grade:

```
int max = grades[0];

for(int i = 1; i < grades.length; i++ ) {
    if(grades[i] > max) {
        max = grades[i];
    }
}  // this loop should end before scoring all students

for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++ ) {
    char score = 'F';
    if      (grades[i] >= max-10) score = 'A';
    else if (grades[i] >= max-20) score = 'B'; 
    else if (grades[i] >= max-30) score = 'C'; 
    else if (grades[i] >= max-40) score = 'D'; 

    System.out.println("Student " + i + " grade=" + grades[i]+ ", score is: " + score);
}
```

Output:

```
Student 0 grade=45, score is: F
Student 1 grade=90, score is: A
Student 2 grade=78, score is: B
Student 3 grade=23, score is: F
```

**Note:** What if the best grade is 50 out of 100, should the students with grades from 40 to 50 still get score `'A'`? :)

Comment: Yeah, based on the assignment I have it's still supposed to be an A grade if the score is very low, which is weird but that's my assignment lol